# I want to compare two datasets to determine which variables they share

Tags: r, comparison, large-data

I have two RNAseq read-outs for two groups and would like to compare them. These data appear as a gene and a value. I would like to determine which genes are shared between the two datasets but they are very large and doing this manually will take a long time. Thanks!

Comment: Just use `intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))`

Comment: What this seems to do is highlight that both columns are called "gene_name". The shared genes will not be aligned

Comment: Could be.  Your question was also not having any reproducible example or expected output so we don't know exactly what you needed

Comment: I'm not really sure of the expected output but I was hoping it would be the common gene name, value for dataset1, value for dataset2

Comment: Right so I've used this code and the common genes have been highlighted. What I was hoping for was a table of common genes with their respective values

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
intersect(genes1, genes2)
```

and look up the help page for other related and useful functions.